# Is there any way to set Database name as global name in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have two databases as mentioned below:

- [QCR_DEV]
- [QCR_DEV_LOG]

All application data are stored in **[QCR_DEV]**. On each table of **[QCR_DEV]**, there is a trigger that insert the details of insertion and update of **[QCR_DEV]** table into **[QCR_DEV_LOG]** database.

Suppose i have a table **[party]** in **[QCR_DEV]** database. Whenever i insert,update or delete some record in the table. There will be one insertion in  table **[party_log]** which exists in  **[QCR_DEV_LOG]** database. In short i am keeping the log or action performed on tables of  **[QCR_DEV]** into **[QCR_DEV_LOG]** database.

When we connect to database through application, it connect to database somehow using connection-string. In my stored procedure, i did not use database name like:

```
Select * From [QCR_DEV].[party];
```

I am using like this:

```
Select * From [party];
```

This is because, in feature if i need to change database name then i will only need to change connection-string.

Now come to the point, i need to get data from [QCR_DEV_LOG] database. I am writing a stored procedure in which i need to get data from both databases like:

```
Select * From [QCR_DEV_LOG][party_log]
INNER JOIN [person] on [person].person_id = [QCR_DEV_LOG][party_log].person_id
where party_id = 1
```

This stored procedure is in [QCR_DEV] database. I need to get data from both databases. For this i need to mention the database name in query. I don't want this. Is there any way to set database name globally and use this name in my queries so that if in future i need to change database name, i only change from where it sets globally. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use SSDT projects for your database source code and create a database reference between the two projects.

Comment: You can create [synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187552) for objects in other databases. You cannot, however, create a synonym for a database.

Comment: @MartinSmith i have a very big database. I can't do this now.

Comment: Definitely have a look at synonyms. They are great for pointing whole loads of queries at a different object/database in a central place. However, like @JeroenMostert said, it has to be at the object, not database level.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, please post your answer so that i can mark it as answer or allow me to mark the answer of Y.B.

Comment: @Umer: since Y.B. actually took the effort to post and answer and even included a neat migration script, by all means accept it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i thought you mentioned the  synonyms idea first, so its your right to have marked answer. BTW thanks.

Comment: @Umer: actually, Stack Overflow is about providing useful answers and comments don't count for anything, which is why you're not supposed to answer questions in comments. I did so anyway because I'm lazy, which should not be rewarded. "I had the idea first" doesn't count for anything on SO. But thanks for your consideration. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would second [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) comment and use synonyms:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [party_log] FOR [QCR_DEV_LOG].[dbo].[party_log];
```

And when the target database is renamed, this query would generate a migration script:

```
SELECT 'DROP SYNONYM [' + name + ']; CREATE SYNONYM [' + name + '] FOR ' + REPLACE(base_object_name, '[OldLogDbName].', '[NewLogDbName].') + ';'
FROM sys.synonyms
WHERE base_object_name LIKE '[OldLogDbName].%';
```

Comment: I guess synonyms are better than views.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in the DEV database:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[party_log]
AS
  SELECT * FROM [QCR_DEV_LOG].[dbo].[party_log]
```

Then you can write SELECT-queries as if the `[party_log]` table exists in the DEV database.

Any `WHERE..` or `JOIN..ON..` clauses should get applied before the combined query is executed.

If the LOG database ever gets moved or renamed, then you'd only need to update the view (or a couple of views, but probably never a lot).

If you expect regular changes, or if you need to use this on multiple servers then you could use dynamic SQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[party_log]') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW [dbo].[party_log]
-- etc, repeat to DROP other views

DECLARE @logdb VARCHAR(80) = 'QCR_DEV_LOG'

EXEC ('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[party_log] AS SELECT * FROM [' + @logdb  + '].[dbo][party_log]')
-- etc, repeat to create other views
```

Comment: If the underlying object for the view would ever change you would have to remember to run `sp_refreshview` on it. This view would be read-only, whereas the synonym can be used for inserts and updates too. The optimizer would have less trouble with synonyms rather than views defined through `SELECT *`

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your answer. Views are usually used for complex data. We consider as view a logical table. No matter i have to do equal work for both Views and synonyms but i think in my case synonym is the better option.

Comment: Sure, also I did not know yet about synonyms, which is useful for me too!